# Automatically insert Entities to IDbSet<> and DbSet<> in DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I was working on my project just writing another entity ( EF code-first) and I realize that amount of those entities in my project getting bigger. I though is it possible somehow automatically register them in DbContext as it possible to register by convention in Unity DI? Is this good practice Or this doesn't make sense at all?

Any feedback or comments on this? Maybe somebody did implementation of this?

Comment: I think the only one way for you to create [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx), that will generate new context.cs file with `DbContext` class and all desired tables.